KDE auto screen brightness stopped working on 24.04 LTS
I have a Dell XPS 15 9510 which was running 22.04 LTS and I recently updated to 24.04 LTS.  In KDE, the auto screen brightness when I connect/disconnect AC power was working fine on 22.04, but now it has stopped working.  I'm still able to control screen brightness with the Fn keys.  All other power settings work and automatically change, such as power profile, keyboard brightness, etc.
I don't even know where to start investigating this issue, so any help here would be appreciated.

I have exactly the same problem, running KDE neon on Dell XPS 13 9350. It stopped working with the Neon upgrade to 24.04.
weirdly, with the Neon USB live image, it works! but installing the system from the same USB, it stopped working! I tried to create a blank user, but the problem is there too.

I have described a workaround here:
https://discuss.kde.org/t/automatic-screen-brightness-stopped-working-after-neon-6-2-install/23915/14?u=slinux
Here is a copy:
I use scripts in the "other settings" section to trigger the brightness adjustment.
The script will read the required brightness value from .config/powerdevilrc and use qdbus6 to set the value.
It works for all 3 modes: AC, Battery and LowBattery.
The script is executed when the energy mode changes (un/plug AC cord) but also when clicking "Apply" on the system settings.
Here is the common script, named brightness-powerdevil.sh, to be saved somewhere accessible from your PATH, for instance $HOME/bin, and made executable with
chmod 755 brightness-powerdevil.sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script can be used to replace the default behaviour of KDE powerdevil
# brightness management, until it is fixed upstream.
# It should be called with parameter "AC" or "Battery" or "LowBattery".
#
# sanette 2024
# https://discuss.kde.org/t/automatic-screen-brightness-stopped-working-after-neon-6-2-install/23915

energy=$1

# We use a log file for debugging
echo $(date) >> /tmp/brightness.log
echo "  Energy=$energy" >> /tmp/brightness.log

# We extract the required value (percentage) from KDE energy system
# settings (powerdevilrc)
sed_exp="sed -n '/^\["$energy"\]\[Display\]/, /^$/p' $HOME/.config/powerdevilrc | sed -n 's/^DisplayBrightness=\([0-9]\+\)/\1/p'"
value=$(eval $sed_exp)

# We get brightnessMax (for me this is 10000)
kdeMax=$(qdbus6 local.org_kde_powerdevil /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/BrightnessControl brightnessMax)

# We convert the percentage value into a correct brightness value
brightness=$(( $value * $kdeMax / 100 ))

# Sleep is not necessary, but it will help noticing when the issue has
# been fixed upstream
sleep 1
echo "  value=$value, Max=$kdeMax, brightness=$brightness" >> /tmp/brightness.log

# We set the new brightness. The advantage compared to directly
# accessing /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness is that
# this should work (with KDE) without sudo
qdbus6 local.org_kde_powerdevil /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/BrightnessControl setBrightness $brightness
# One could also use setBrightnessSilent to suppress onscreen notification

The in the "other settings" of the Energy settings panel, enter the name of the following scripts: brightness-ac.sh, brightness-battery.sh, and brightness-lowbattery.sh in the correspondig tabs (don't forget chmod 755)
$ more brightness-ac.sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script can be used to replace the default behaviour of KDE powerdevil
# brightness management, until it is fixed upstream.
# It should be called when AC power is plugged in: see the Energy system settings.
#
# sanette 2024
# https://discuss.kde.org/t/automatic-screen-brightness-stopped-working-after-neon-6-2-install/23
915

brightness-powerdevil.sh AC

$ more brightness-battery.sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script can be used to replace the default behaviour of KDE
# powerdevil brightness management, until it is fixed upstream.  It
# should be called when entering Battery mode (AC power is unplugged):
# see the Energy system settings.
#
# sanette 2024
# https://discuss.kde.org/t/automatic-screen-brightness-stopped-working-after-neon-6-2-install/23
915

brightness-powerdevil.sh Battery

$ more brightness-lowbattery.sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script can be used to replace the default behaviour of KDE powerdevil
# brightness management, until it is fixed upstream.
# It should be called when entering Low Battery Mode: see the Energy system settings.
#
# sanette 2024
# https://discuss.kde.org/t/automatic-screen-brightness-stopped-working-after-neon-6-2-install/23
915

brightness-powerdevil.sh LowBattery

